# use ArrayList as filter in linq query "where" keyword

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have some data in an ArrayList and I would like to use that to filter my Linq query using the where clause.

My Linq code below joins two tables and then I filter them using the Where clause. Now I would like to FURTHER filter this query by using the Arraylist as a filter. So the value come from arraylist

I would like the "where" clause to take one more comparison and the value comes from an arraylist:

```
where rType.Field<string>("ProfSSCMName") == lbProfiles.SelectedValue && rType.Field<string>("Name") == lbHWTypes.SelectedValue && **arrayList.Tostring()**
```

This is the code that I am using.

Can anyone tell me how can I further filter my Linq query using the values in the arraylist?

```
joined = from rType in ds.Tables["HWTypes"].AsEnumerable()
         join rStock in ds.Tables["Stock"].AsEnumerable()
         on rType.Field<string>("ProductID") equals rStock.Field<string>("Partno")
         where rType.Field<string>("ProfSSCMName") == lbProfiles.SelectedValue && rType.Field<string>("Name") == lbHWTypes.SelectedValue
         select new
         {
             TagNumber = rStock.Field<string>("TagNumber"),
             SerialNumber = rStock.Field<string>("SerialNumber"),
             Partno = rStock.Field<string>("Partno"),
             PartType = rStock.Field<string>("PartType"),
             EcopartSubtype = rStock.Field<string>("EcopartSubtype"),
             AzertyQuerty = rStock.Field<string>("Azerty/Querty"),
             ProductID = rType.Field<string>("ProductID"),
             Name = rType.Field<string>("Name"),
             SCCMKeyboard = rType.Field<string>("SCCMKeyboard"),
             DisplayName = rType.Field<string>("DisplayName"),
             ProfSSCMName = rType.Field<string>("ProfSSCMName"),
             TagNameDisplayName = rStock.Field<string>("TagNumber") + " " + rType.Field<string>("DisplayName")

             // add the other columns you need here
         };
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using an ArrayList instead of a strongly typed [Generic List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

Comment: It does not matter what it is. It can be a Generic List or whatever. The important thing is that it is a collection and I have to filter my Linq query based on this collection before I can display the results. can you tell me how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using Linq-To-Objects.
So you can just use contains on the arraylist

```
where rType.Field<string>("ProfSSCMName") == lbProfiles.SelectedValue 
&& rType.Field<string>("Name") == lbHWTypes.SelectedValue 
&& arrayList.Contains( rType.Field<string>("Name") )
```

Comment: do I do that without looping the array list?

Comment: Yes, you just want to test that the row contains one of the values in the arraylist as I understand it.

Comment: @AdamMills in 'Contains' will use loop or i miss something?! But i can't understand how it can be without it, so i upvote you :)

Comment: @Likurg - Yes, internally the Contains method of ArrayList will loop over its contents.